# Is $S\in R$ under the binary operation $x\times y=x+y-5$ a group?

Tags: group-theory

I'm still having a fair bit of trouble with calculating the identity and inverses of operations like this. Would I be right in saying that the identity is 5, since $x\times e$ must equal x, so then $x\times 5=x+5-5=x$?

For the inverse I would now need $x$ $\times$ $x$ inverse to be equal to 5. For example, taking x=2, I would need 2$\times$(inverse)=2+inverse-5, which need to be equal to my identity, 5. This is just simple algebraic manipulation, so each element would have an inverse then?

And then of course since all addition and subtraction of real numbers are associative, so would this one. Is this the right thinking? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, your ideas are correct. Dont forget closure btw (although it is obvious)

Answer (score 1):

We could verify the various "group properties" one after the other. You have made a good beginning on that. There is a more abstract but easier way.

Define the mapping $\phi$ from the reals under addition to our structure by $\phi(w)=w+5$. Then 
$$\phi(x+y)=x+y+5=(x+5)+(y+5)-5=\phi(x)+\phi(y)-5=\phi(x)\times\phi(y).$$
It is easy to check that $\phi$ is one to one and onto. Thus $\phi$ is an isomorphism from the reals under addition to our structure. In particular, our structure is a group.

Comment: An example of [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure).